Set the HMAC-256 algorithm for calculating message-authenticator
Per radius document:

When present in an Access-Request packet, Message-Authenticator is an HMAC-MD5 checksum of the entire Access-Request packet, including Type, ID, Length and authenticator, using the shared secret as the key

but if using the HMAC-MD5 algorithm, hackers can easily break data packets between radius and NAS.
Is it possible to set the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm for calculating and checking message-authenticator in freeradius?
Special reminder, this is RADIUS/NAS encryption, not user-password encryption.
Currently, I plan to use HMAC-SHA256 algorithm for calculating message-authenticator in NAS,
I want to set the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm for calculating message-authenticator in freeradius.

No.  FreeRADIUS implements Message-Authenticator as per RFC2869 which uses an MD5 HMAC.  The IETF is deprecating RADIUS in the clear, new implementations should use RADSEC (RADIUS over TLS).

Thank you for your response, I also want to ask, according to draft radius 1.1（ https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-radext-radiusv11/01/ ) : "  The Message-Authenticator attribute ([RFC3579] Section 3.2) is not sent in any packet, and if received is ignored"  May I ask if this has been implemented in Freeradius?
